# Cannot figure out error with C++ exception

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to figure out what the error I am having in my code however when print out the message, it says "Use askUserMessage () or askSyslogMessage ()" and I don't know what that means.

Here is my code snippet:

```
try
{
    // Instantiate the Xerces DOM parser
    parser = new SAXParser();
}
catch (const SAXParseException& toCatch) {
    char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
    fverbose ( AFCCB2MMLAdapter::logFile, message );            
    return NULL;
}
catch (const std::exception& ex)
{
    printf("Error = %s\n", ex.what());

    //fverbose ( AFCCB2MMLAdapter::logFile, ex.what() );            
    return NULL;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste in the error verbatim? It seems you are paraphrasing the error.

Comment: the Actual display is: Error = Use askUserMessage ( ) or askSyslogMessage ( )

Comment: Have you put breakpoints in to see where this error is actually occuring? It appears to be telling you to use an alternate method due to a deprecation or something.

Comment: Thanks Mike, the error seems to be at the "parser = new SAXParser();" line however I'm kind of stumped as to what the heck the message means.

Comment: I would research what askUserMessage() and the other are, so that you may determine if they would be alternatives to SAXParser(), perhaps they are and that will solve your issue

Comment: I have done a google search and come up with no recognizable matches to askUserMessage or askSysLogMessage ... btw I am using the xerces dll to try and do some xml parsing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was an issue with the xerces parser. This code was migrated from an older version and apparently the older version didn't require initialization of the XML parser, however the new version does

I've added a call to the Initialization routine and now the error has gone away.

Thanks for your help!

Kevin